# problem passing values via XCom in my Airflow DAG

Tags: airflow, dockeroperator

I'm trying to pass a value  from one  Task to another in my DAG.

I have this piece  of  code in my DockerOperator task:

```
'''ti = kwargs['ti']'''

'''command=ti.xcom_pull(key='return_value', task_ids=['run_this']),'''
```

Yet  I am get error **'invalid syntax'** from this  line with 'ti.xcom_pull'  above.

This  DAG has  two  tasks,  the first  one is Task ID **run_this** which calls a Python Callable Function called **run_this_now** that has this as its  return statement:
return payload

I am looking at the UI under  Admin-->XComs and see the key 'return_value' with its value as shown to be returned by task ID 'run_this'.

So I know I have  an XCom  with a return value and  yet the  syntax  is still giving  me this   error.

I am running Airflow 2.0.2

Comment: We can't do much without a complete code example and/or stacktrace. Please rephrase your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was  to use double  {{'s under  the DockerOperator
I didn't need  to reference  the variable as the run_this  function  only returned one value via 'return' statement

```
    command="{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids = 'run_this')}}",
```